# select all of table A left join column of table B with multiple wheres that dont affect showing all of table A

Tags: php, mysql

I have a work order tracking site. On my new_workorder.php script my form is dynamically generated by values in table `cl_billing_codes`. When the form is submitted, the values go into `cl_work_order_billing_codes` with the code id, and the quantity and a column with the work order id to tie the values to the work order.

I am in the process of trying to build an edit_workorder.php script. I need to pull all the values of `cl_billing_codes` while left joining the quantities of the user submitted data from the new_workorder.php form. Here is my best effort.

```
SELECT
  `cl_billing_codes`.`id`                          AS `id`,
  `cl_billing_codes`.`billing_code`                AS `billing_code`,
  `cl_billing_codes`.`desc`                        AS `desc`,
  `cl_billing_codes`.`point_value`                 AS `point_value`,
  `cl_work_orders_billing_codes`.`quantity`        AS `quantity`,
  `cl_work_orders_billing_codes`.`billing_code_id` AS `id2`
FROM
  `cl_billing_codes`
  LEFT JOIN `cl_work_orders_billing_codes`
      ON `billing_code` = `cl_work_orders_billing_codes`.`billing_code_id`
WHERE
  `cl_billing_codes`.`service` = '1'
  AND `cl_work_orders_billing_codes`.`work_order_id` = 1585
ORDER BY `billing_code`
```

Doing it this way doesn't work because I need all the data in `cl_billing_codes` where the `service` column equals 1, but only the quantity values in the `cl_work_order_billing_codes` where the `work_order_id` value in that table equals a defined value and the billing codes match in both tables.

///// Additional /////

Here is a sample of my table data to work with.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49783/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to move the condition on the `work_orders_billing_codes` table into the `on` clause.  Then if there is no match, you will still get all the appropraite records in `billing_codes`.

```
SELECT bc.`id` AS `id`, bc.`billing_code` AS `billing_code`, bc.`desc` AS `desc`,
       bc.`point_value` AS `point_value`,
       wobc.`quantity` AS `quantity`,
       wobc.`billing_code_id` AS `id2` 
FROM `cl_billing_codes` bc LEFT JOIN
     `cl_work_orders_billing_codes` wobc
     ON bc.id = wobc.`billing_code_id` AND wobc.`work_order_id` = 1585
WHERE bc.`service` =  '1' 
ORDER BY `billing_code`;
```

Comment: This returns all the quantity values as NULL even though you can see from my sample data that quantity for work_order_id 1585 has plenty of records in the cl_work_orders_billing_codes table. It is a lot closer than I got though. :\

Comment: @JesseWilliamSzypulski . . . The problem is the join.  You had `billing_code`.  However, you wanted `id`.  The edited version now works.

Comment: Thank you :) that is exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't sure how to use two different types of specific 'where' data.